# Unable to Redirect Standard Input

Tags: .net, vb.net, cmd

I asked this question with a different title before I knew exactly what I was looking for; reposting it with a clear title in hopes I'll get some answers.

I'm trying to redirect the standard input to an application so I can control it from my Visual Basic program.

```
Public Class MyClass
    Dim StreamWriteUtility As System.IO.StreamWriter
    Dim StreamReadUtility As System.IO.StringReader
    Dim ProcessInfo As ProcessStartInfo
    Dim Process As Process

    Public Sub StartUSBCapture(ByVal DataStorageLocation As String)

        ProcessInfo = New ProcessStartInfo("C:\FW_Qualification_Suite\data-center-windows\data-center\bin\datacenter.cmd", "-c ")
        ProcessInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
        ProcessInfo.UseShellExecute = False 'Must be changed if redirect set to True
        ProcessInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True

        Process.Start(ProcessInfo)

        StreamWriteUtility = Process.StandardInput

        While True
        StreamWriteUtility.WriteLine("run") 'Looping for test to ensure this isn't a timing issue
        End While
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Using Avast?  Then uninstall it.

Comment: @Hans: Nope, not using Avast.

Comment: try doing this ........... shell("cmd.exe /c cd C:\FW_Qualification_Suite\data-center-windows\data-center\bin\ & datacenter.cmd & PAUSE", AppWinStyle.NormalFocus, True, -1) ............ to see if eveything is running ok ..... Also, do you mean "While SWUtility" or "While True"?

Comment: If there is another _similar_ question, you should perhaps provide a link to it... if you posted the _same_ question twice (with different title only), you should delete one of those as double-posting is discouraged on SO...

Comment: @Nefariis: that line works fine: the application launches, as well as a command line. The line `While True` was intended to cause the program to continually try to write to the command line. However, as I said it never reaches that line.

Answer (score 0):

I see a few syntax errors that might be giving you your troubles. For example, you need to be reading standard input into a `StreamWriter` and not into whatever `SWUtility` is (you never defined it), also the sytnax to start a process is just `process.start` it's not `process = process.start`. Lastly, you are missing `process.WaitForExit()` which could definitely be messing everything up.

```
Public Class MyClass
    Dim sw As System.IO.StreamWriter
    Dim sr As System.IO.StreamReader
    Dim ProcessInfo As New ProcessStartInfo
    Dim Process As New Process

    Public Sub StartUSBCapture(ByVal DataStorageLocation As String)

        ProcessInfo = New ProcessStartInfo("C:\FW_Qualification_Suite\data-center-windows\data-center\bin\datacenter.cmd")
        ProcessInfo.Arguments = "-c"
        ProcessInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
        ProcessInfo.UseShellExecute = False 
        ProcessInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
        ProcessInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
        Process.Startinfo = ProcessInfo
        Process.Start()

        Process.StandardInput.WriteLine("Your Line")
        Process.StandardInput.WriteLine("Your Line 2")
        Process.StandardInput.WriteLine("Exit")

        sw = Process.StandardInput
        sr = Process.StandardOutput

        Dim line As String
        Do
            Line = sr.ReadLine()
            MsgBox(line)
        Loop Until line Is Nothing
        sr.Close()
     End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had boggled the code I posted a bit; I've cleaned it up.  Your suggestions has an issue with the use of "Process.WaitForExit(). I am not looking to close the application until I've been able to send it commands. So the WaitForExit causes my app to pause indefinitely until the user closes the other app, and thus never gets to the section where my app should be sending commands. Also, the syntax for starting the process seems to make no difference here, but I've cleaned that up too to avoid confusion.

Comment: I successfully got this to work (obviously not with your exact command), it successfully reads an input and prints an output... The "Exit" or "exit" might be necessary (try both).

Comment: I don't get it. Doesn't work for me at all. Doesn't even launch my app.